# Swift editing related Core Data objects with NSFetchedResultsController across views / how do I format and use NSPredicate with a block?

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a question regarding **editing/deleting** Core Data objects in a `UIListView` that are related to another object.

To simplify the problem, let's say I have a list view of `Family` objects. Tapping on a Family name opens a list view of `FamilyMember` objects for the chosen `Family` object. I have a one to many relationship between `Family` and `FamilyMember` set up in Core Data.

I perform an `NSFetchRequest` to grab the list of all 'Family' objects in my initial table view controller and put them into an `NSFetchedResultsController`. When a family in the list is tapped, that 'Family' object is passed into the `FamilyMembersViewController` with `prepareForSegue`.

The issue I'm facing is that since I passed in a 'Family' object directly from the initial view controller to `FamilyMembersViewController`, I never had to create a FetchRequest or a `NSFetchedResultsController` in `FamilyMembersViewController`. Therefore, some editing functions that worked great on the initial view now don't work in the `FamilyMembersViewController`.

How do I take advantage of `NSFetchedResultsController` functions (such as the following) in a view that doesn't have a `NSFetchedResultsController`? Do I need to re-query Core Data, limiting the results to a specific 'Family" object? It seems like a waste since I already have the object available in my view.

Am I approaching this functionality incorrectly? I guess I'm just hoping to have the functions be similar from one view controller to the next.

I've tried making a new array called 'familyMembers' and a corresponding `NSFetchedResultsController` within my `FamilyMembersViewController` and predicated it with this:

```
var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "family == %@", "\(self.family)")
```

where `self.family` is the 'Family' object passed from the `initialView`. But in this case, for some reason the "self.family" part just returns an empty string, when really it should return the Family object. Even if it did return the Family object, it doesn't seem like passing that into the predicate would help anything, since the predicate seems to match only strings. I can't quite figure out how to format a Predicate with a block statement.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you for reading.

```
func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController!) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController!, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject!, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    switch type {
    case .Insert:
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    case .Delete:
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    case .Update:
        tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    default:
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    families = controller.fetchedObjects as [Family]
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController!) {
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track, though predicate arguments don't have to be strings - you can pass the family object itself:

```
var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "family == %@", self.family)
```

Comment: Where do you apply the predicate in the code above? I don't see it anywhere. I'm struggling with this myself.

Comment: @kakubei - the predicate is used when configuring the NSFetchedResultsController (which isn't in the code above).  When you define the fetch underlying the FRC, you set `fetch.predicate = predicate`.